# Ajax: получение части кода со страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter

Нужно получить часть кода из блока `#id` с другой страницы как с помощью `.load('url #id')`, но `.load()` не получает код скриптов внутри `#id`.

```
function ocmenu(linkurl){
    $.ajax({
        url: linkurl,
        cache: true
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $('.new').append(html);
    });
}
```

`html.filter('#id')` не работает

Comment: я же вам говорил, что вообще не надо так скрипты получать, неужели у вас задача, где это необходимо таки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное надо попробовать так, аякс возвращает Вам строку, чтобы воспользоваться функциями jQuery Вам надо преобразовать в jQuery объект:

```
...
.done(function(html){
    $(html).filter('#id');
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь что не будет работать но все же попробуйте

```
html = html.children('#id');
```

А вообще это надо делать на регулярном выражении...