# Вывод данных с другой страницы сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает код на **Ajax**. Пытаюсь получить код с другой страницы того же домена с class'а (`.content`) и вставить в class (`.container`), но все безуспешно.

```
function ocmenu(http://site.ru/victim.html){
    $.ajax({
        url: http://site.ru/victim.html,
        cache: true
    }).done(function(html){
        $(html).filter('.content'); 
        $('.container').append(html); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: вы ведь понимаете, что приведенный JavaScript код невалиден?

Comment: Не понимаю, опыта работы с js, ajax не было, только с++, в интернете несколько решений есть на мою задачу, и ни дно не работает, потому что везде чего-то не хватает.

Comment: Тогда я могу посоветовать только один путь -- учите js, правьте код, чтобы он был, как минимум, корректен и задавайте конкретные вопросы.

Comment: DmitriySimushev имеет ввиду, что проблема Вашего кода, это но просто проблема новичка. Подобный подход в любом языке программирования выдаст ошибки. Конкретно, в обоих случаях, где вы указываете url. В первом случае (параметр функции) он вообще не нужен, или должен быть заменен на переменную. Во втором, url сайта должен быть в кавычках. Если после исправления все равно работать не будет - нужны  будут детали, чтобы помочь: html, содержимое консоли...

Comment: Я прошу лишь объяснить, где ошибки и из-за чего может не работать код, насчет функции, согласен, в каждой функции в скобках должна быть переменная, а потом этой переменной присваивается значение, но в исходном коде этой переменной ничего не передавалось и вместо linkurl пишут просто url, вот что сбивает с толку в каждом чужом коде... сам оригинал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244505/ajax-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: @Дмитрий попробуйте сделать как в оригинале.. то есть заменить `http://site.ru/victim.html` на `linkurl` а потом, чтобы вызвать функцию... где-нибудь внизу напишите её вызов `ocmenu('http://site.ru/victim.html');` ....... ошибка в том, что вы должны использовать входной параметр и подставлять его там, где необходимо......а при вызове функции как раз задавать значение этому входному параметру

Comment: Вы хотите на одной странице вывести другую страницу или вы хотите выполнить какую то операцию с данными и вывести результат в определенный блок?

Comment: thecoder, я хочу получить код html с другой страницы, обработать его(взять определенные данные) и вывести в другом классе\блоке.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, попробовал запустить функцию и передать ссылку, не происходит, (использовал функцию    function ocmenu(linkurl){
            $.ajax({
      url: linkurl,
  cache: true
}).done(function(html){
    $(html).filter('.content2'); 
    $('.container2').append(html); 
});
<p onclick="ocmenu(http://site.ru/page2.html)">ClickClack</p> - для вызова)

Comment: @Дмитрий вы опять не обрамили url кавычками, в данном случае они должны быть одинарными `ocmenu('site.ru/page2.html')"` чтобы не пересекались с кавычками в которых значение атрибута

Comment: @Дмитрий, не помогает

Comment: ссылка на пациента http://vse-dlya-evreev.ru/

Comment: @Дмитрий У вашего дохлого пациента во-первых не хватает `}` в конце, а во-вторых не подключена библиотека `jquery`, для того, чтобы работал `$.ajax`

Comment: @Дмитрий, огромное Спасибо, все заработало! Ну наконец-то!))

Comment: Так, а как теперь получить только содержимое "content"? Почему не работает filter(content)?

Comment: @Дмитрий, почитайте справку: [что именно делает функция фильтр](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел отличное решение моей проблемы:

```
 function ocmenu(linkurl){
  $( "#container2" ).load( "otherPage.html #content" );
 }
```